# python datatype like 2d named list in R

Tags: python, r, list, dictionary

I'm porting my code from R to python at the moment. The list datatype has a very useful property in R and I'm wondering if I can do the same in python.
If I have following named list:

```
named_list <- list(
  first_item = list(1, 2, 3),
  second_item = list(4, 5, 6)
)
```

[image: named_list]

I can "transpose" it with the purrr library. (Which is extremly fast even with huge datasets)

```
transposed_list <- purrr::transpose(.l = named_list)
```

And get following list returned, which has all indexes in its first dimension and the names in the second dimension.

[image: transposed_list]

Can we do something similar in python with dictionaries or any other data type?

Comment: This looks like a job for `zip` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same with lists of lists in python by using [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [*splat](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
>>> list_ = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> zip(*list_)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Note that you get tuples inside instead of lists. If you need the lists, use `map(list, zip(*l))`

If you're open to using numpy instead of a list of lists, then using the `.T` attribute is even easier:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> print(*a)
[1 2 3] [4 5 6]
>>> print(*a.T)
[1 4] [2 5] [3 6]
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. Cheers!